# Find the resistance in a mixed circuit

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance

I have this circuit and from what I understand to find the resistance of $R_1$ I need to use $V = RI$.  So I found the Voltage for $R_2$ to be $1.5$ V and the voltage for $R_3$ to be $0.996$ V.  What I don't understand is, if I add that up it gives $2.46$ V, which is more volts than the source of $1.5$ V.  I was planning on subtracting the total voltage of $R_2$ and $R_3$ from the total voltage and from there find the resistance of $R_1$, but it doesn't seem possible.

[image: Mixed Circuit]

Comment: If all that current goes through R2, there's nothing left for R1...

Comment: Please show the calculations that give you those values. I very much doubt the voltage across $R_2$ to be equal to the source's.

Comment: V= R*I and so 2.5(R2) * 0.6(I) = 1.5

Comment: All the $0.6$ A don't go through $R_2$ alone. Some goes through $R_1$. Do you know Kirchhoff's laws https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws?

Comment: So does this mean that since it branches that 0.3 amps go into each branch?

Comment: It's like water. If a streams splits into two equally wide, then yes, the water divides equally. But if one is more narrow, it has more "resistance" against the flow, and less will flow through and more through the other. Same goes for current. Kirchhoff's current law says that all that flows in must also flow out - and it will happen in proportion to the resistances.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the steps you can do are the following:

1. Find voltage over $R_3$ with Ohm's law.
2. Find voltage over the parallel portion with Kirchhoff's voltage law.
3. Find current through $R_2$ with Ohm's law.
4. Find current through $R_1$ with Kirchhoff's current law.
5. Rind resistance $R_1$ with Ohm's law.

In short the laws...

- Ohm's law (for a component):
  $$V=RI$$
- Kirchhoff's current law (for a point on the path): $$\quad\sum I=0 \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \sum I_{in}=\sum I_{out}$$
- Kirchhoff's voltage law (for a loop): $$\quad\sum_{loop} V =0 $$

So, if a path splits in two, then some of the current takes one path and the rest the other. How much depends on the resistances. And, along any loop, all the voltages of all components can be added together and much give 0.

An understanding of Kirchhoff's laws of current conservation and balanced voltage loops is essential:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws

Comment: So what I get from this is what goes into the branch is what comes out of the branch when it comes back together.  What I don't see in this wiki page is any kind of formula for calculating the amps in each branch according to it's resistances.  Can you help me here?

Comment: @lehast22 See the addition to the answer. Kirchhoff's law only says that the sum of incoming and outgoing currents is $0$. It doesn't combine it with the resistances. This is what Ohm's law does. Follow the five steps above, where you must use the three laws in different cases, and the result will hopefully appear.

Comment: @lehast22 No problem. I hope it works out, otherwise write again